# If I have binary predictor and 1 categorical response (3 classes), how do I test hypothesis?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

If I have binary predictor and 1 categorical response (3 classes), how do I test hypothesis that the three classes give the same mean, etc?

Any link or answer is appreciated

Comment: Clarification about "the three classes give the same mean" would be helpful. I have responded with my best interpretation of that.

Comment: @ewfoew Can we have some clarification?  It sounds like the response is categorical.  Are you interested in examining id the class probabilities are different conditioned on the binary predictor?

Comment: Same mean on what?

Answer (score 1):

You want to reverse the problem: use the three classes to predict the binary outcome. This is essentially ANOVA but with a binary response instead of a normal response.

I would use logistic regression and likelihood ratio test the model with the three-level categorical predictor (and an intercept) against a model with just an intercept. (This is essentially what ANOVA does.)

This is easy to implement in R as well as other software. I will give an R example with a binary predictor, but you can tweak this for your problem with a three-way predictor.

```
library(lmtest)
set.seed(2020)
x <- rbinom(500, 1, 0.5)
y <- rbinom(500, 1, 0.5)
g_full <- glm(y~x, family="binomial")
g_reduced <- glm(y~1, family="binomial")
lrtest(g_full, g_reduced)
```

That final line with the `lrtest` does the likelihood ratio test to see if the predictor category influences the response.

Comment: This would give you $P(X=x \vert Y=y)$ seems temporally backwards.  Ostensibly, you would know $X$ before $Y$, so shouldn't the conditioning respect this temporal relationship?

Comment: I think the OP is asking about what’s going on what what she thinks is her predictor but is actually the response variable. Perhaps further clarification will reveal if I am right to think of this like an ANOVA but with proportions instead of Gaussians, but that was my read of the question. “Do all three of these categories have the same mean?” sounds like ANOVA.

Comment: Yea, I think there needs to be some clarification of the question first.